# Web player without spotify desktop application

Tags: api, spotify

I use Spotify Play Button (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/) but it launch spotify desktop application when click on play. Now http://play.spotify.com has been released, is it possible to play sounds directly with Spotify Play Button ?

Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No — the Play Button requires the Spotify Desktop Application at the moment.

Edit: As of now (Jan 2014), the Play Button will now use the web player if the desktop client isn't installed.